# Valid md5/sha1/etc input characters?

Tags: hash, input, character-encoding, md5, sha1

What characters are valid inputs for the common hash methods.  I'm guessing every possible symbol known to man/computer isn't a valid input.

Answer (score 2):

The input of md5/sha1/5 is **not** characters/symbols but bytes. So that makes your question kinda moot.

All byte sequences are valid input.

Characters and symbols are ambiguous and cannot be hashed. What is the md5 of `a`? If you are answering that, you are wrongly assuming ASCII even though I could encode it in UTF-16/32 or EBCDIC for a completely different hash. Don't get me started on a non-ASCII symbol or a character. So the question is ambiguous unless I mention the input in bytes or characters + character encoding.

I recommend reading [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/).